# Show one item per category of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I'm having a custom type called portfolio with different categories. I want to display all my categories except one. I only want to show one item per category on my page.

I'm been busting my butt on this and i only get my loop to show all the items in the category but can't get only one item per category. So far i get to display the categories, but they repeat itself, i can't get it to show just once on the page. One category per page.

here is the two loops i tried.

Loop1

```
$args = array (
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'category__not_in' => array(28,30),
    );

    $newQuery = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($newQuery -> have_posts() ):
        while( $newQuery-> have_posts() ): $newQuery-> the_post();
            echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID , 'portfolio_type'); 
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Test loop 2

```
$args_cat = array (
        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
        'exclude' =>  '28,30',
    );
    $categories = get_categories($args_cat);

    foreach($categories as $category):

        $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
        );

        $newQuery = new WP_Query($args);

        if ($newQuery -> have_posts() ):
            while( $newQuery-> have_posts() ): $newQuery-> the_post();

                echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID , 'portfolio_type'); 

            endwhile;
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach;
```

Can anyone help me thanks?!

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
                    'exclude' => '28,30',
                    );
                $tax = get_terms($args);
                foreach($tax as $t){




                    echo '<div class="span3 produto-lista">';

                        $args = array(

                                  'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_type',
                                        'field' => 'slug',
                                        'terms' => array($t->slug)
                                    )
                                ),
                                  'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                                  'order' => 'DESC',

                                  );
                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );




                        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                            $query->the_post();

                            ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($t); ?>">

                            <?php
                            the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            <h1>
                            <?php
                            echo $t->name; 
                            ?>
                            </h1>
                            </a>
                            <?php
                        }
                        wp_reset_query();
                    echo '</div>';
                }
```